# Изображение по клеткам - DrawGrid

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, есть вопрос. Вообщем есть Memo1 и DrawGrid1. DrawGrid1 имеет 5 столбцов и 5 строк. В мемо текст:

```
00010
10100
00100
01001
10010
```

вообщем имеет текст 5 символов(1 или 0) и пять строк с такими символами... Так вот каждая строчка в Memo отвечает за строчку в DrawGrid. Мне надо, чтобы в каждую к каждой клетке в DrawGrid присоеденилось одно число и закрасило его, то есть первая строчка DrawGrid = первая строчка Memo -> В Memo имеем 01100 при этом срабатывает условие для кажой клетки, если 0, то белый цвет, если 1, то черный. Должно получить в DrawGrid клетки: белый черный черный белый белый. И так для каждой строчки...

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось это:

```
procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
Var
  Str: String;
  i, j, n, len: Byte;

begin
  N:=Memo1.Lines.Count-1;
  For i:=0 To N Do
    Begin
      Str:=Memo1.Lines.Strings[i];
      Len:=Length(Str);
      For j:=1 To Len Do
        Begin
          If (Str[j]='0') Then
            With DrawGrid1.Canvas Do
              Begin
                Brush.Color:=clWhite;
                Font.Color:=clBlack;
                FillRect(DrawGrid1.CellRect(j-1, i));
                TextOut(DrawGrid1.CellRect(j-1, i).Left+2,
                  DrawGrid1.CellRect(j-1, i).Top+2, '0');
              End
          Else If (Str[j]='1') Then
            With DrawGrid1.Canvas Do
              Begin
                Brush.Color:=clBlack;
                Font.Color:=clWhite;
                FillRect(DrawGrid1.CellRect(j-1, i));
                TextOut(DrawGrid1.CellRect(j-1, i).Left+2,
                  DrawGrid1.CellRect(j-1, i).Top+2, '1');
              End
          Else
            With DrawGrid1.Canvas Do
              Begin
                Brush.Color:=clBlack;
                Font.Color:=clWhite;
              End;

          If (j>=DrawGrid1.ColCount) Then
            Break;
        End;

      If (i>=DrawGrid1.RowCount) Then
        Break;
    End;
end;
```

А при нажатии на кнопку, надо написать строку:

```
DrawGrid1.Repaint;
```

Предлагаю ещё сделать проверку, когда пользователь вводит символы в Мемо (написать обработчик события OnKeyPress).